# Select id based on label

Tags: javascript, jquery, label

So I'm working on a plugin for a specific website, my issue is that they change the names & id's dynamically so I can only use the Label Name as the selector. My issue is that have I have 2 selections that I need to fill but only one label to go off from.

HTML:

```
<div class="input string required">
    <label class="string required control-label" for="credit_card_month">exp. date</label>
    <select id="credit_card_month" name="credit_card[month]">
        <option value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02">02</option>
        <option value="03">03</option>
        <option value="04">04</option>
        <option value="05">05</option>
        <option value="06">06</option>
        <option value="07">07</option>
        <option value="08">08</option>
        <option value="09">09</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <select id="credit_card_year" name="credit_card[year]">
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
        <option value="2021">2021</option>
        <option value="2022">2022</option>
        <option value="2023">2023</option>
        <option value="2024">2024</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
$('label:contains("exp. date")').parent('div').find('select').val("08");
$('label:contains("exp. date")').parent('div').find('select').val("2016");
```

The [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqajjxvt/), any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**.eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) allows you to select from a jQuery object by index. [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kqajjxvt/1/)

```
var select = $('label:contains("exp. date")').parent('div').find('select');

select.eq(0).val("08"); // first select box

select.eq(1).val("2016"); // second select box
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can place the results of on selector into a variable to perform the second `val()` http://jsfiddle.net/kqajjxvt/2/

Comment: Awesome, I learned something today. I've been messing with it all day and you solved it in less than 5 minutes. Cheers!

Comment: Everyone has been exposed to different approaches, that's what makes Stackoverflow so great! Keep the questions coming :)

Answer (score 0):

Find by your select id's. I'm also trying to figure out why you're selecting by content of the label tags, that's not a good idea.

```
$('label.control-label').parent('div').find('select#credit_card_month').val("08");
$('label.control-label').parent('div').find('select#credit_card_year').val("2016");
```

Comment: The ID's are changed dynamically from time to time so the only static item that remains is the label. thanks!